Are these statements about the unary union and intersection operators correct?
Just checking my understanding...
Is it correct to say:

For any family of sets $F$ (possibly empty):


$\forall x:[x\in \cup F \iff \exists y: [y \in F \land x \in y]]$


For any NON-EMPTY family of sets $F$:


$\forall x:[x\in \cap F \iff \forall y: [y \in F \implies x \in y]]$


Both of these appear correct to me.
